# How to Implement Solrnet in Mvc 3 Project with facet and weights

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solrnet, facet

I have found many examples but not a single example which runs properly. I am having trouble.

I want to implement Solrnet in MVC3 and want to search with facets and weights.

I tried this example but it gives me an error:[https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/ee56b02c913a9b52459cefe1cc1623cc254d5f3b]

Please give me an example which works properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "weightage"? What error do you get? Also that link does not exist.

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet You can see this example and it gives "The controller for path '/solr/update' could not be found or it does not implement IController." this error. Please resolve this issue.

Comment: What example? It seems you're trying to use the SolrNet sample app as a replacement for Solr. SolrNet is only a *client* for Solr, so you can talk to Solr from a .NET application.